# Getting date difference of the Date stored at the database and the current date

Tags: mysql

I am having difficulties on getting the date difference of the date stored in my database to the current day. This is my sample code:

```html
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei');
$date = $_POST['date_posted']; //Date from the database
$now = new DateTime(); //Current date

echo $date->diff($now)->format("%y year/s, %m month/s, %d day/s");
?>
```

I'm new to this one so I am very confuse on the other codes.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one hopw it will work

```
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");//database date
$date2=date_create(date('Y-m-d'));//today date
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%y year/s, %m month/s, %d day/s");
```